# SQL - Using CTE to pass CASE statement results to subsequent formulas/CASE statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, common-table-expression

I'm trying to use CTEs to pass results from CASE statements as inputs to subsequent CASE statements on minute-level date before aggregating to daily values. The intention of the code below is to:

1. First query all of the relevant fields into CTE_1 from the relevant tables (POIData, InverterData, and WeatherStationData) joining and grouping by the common Timestamp_UTC column
2. Create several new fields in CTE_1 ([Year], [Mon], [Day], [Sum_Meter_KWh], [Sum_Expected_KWh], [Curtailed_Energy_KWh], and [Inv_Count])
3. Query all of the fields from CTE_1 into CTE_2 and use the fields created in CTE_1 ([Inv_Count], [Sum_Meter_KWh], [Sum_Expected_KWh] and [Curtailed_Energy_KWh]) to calculate new fields in CTE_2 ([Availability_InvTime(%)] and [Energetic_Avail(%)]) and aggregate/group minute-level data into Year, Month, Day
4. Query all fields from CTE_2 and order by Year, Month, Day

EDITED 6/7/2022 11:33AM CST*
'''

```
WITH
    CTE_1 AS
        (SELECT        
                POIData.Timestamp_UTC as [TimeDate],
                SUM(POIData.Meter_KW/60) as [Sum_Meter_KWh],
                SUM(POIData.Park_Potential_KW/60) as [Sum_Expected_KWh],
                SUM(CASE
                        WHEN (POIData.Park_Potential_KW > POIData.Meter_KW)
                            AND POIData.Meter_KW>=0
                            AND POIData.Park_Potential_KW>=0      
                            AND (WeatherStationData.Valid = 1)
                            AND (POIData.Valid = 1)
                            AND (WeatherStationData.GPOA_1 > 50)
                            AND (POIData.Power_Limit_SP < 120000)
                            AND (POIData.Park_Potential_KW > POIData.Power_Limit_SP)
                        THEN (POIData.Park_Potential_KW/60) - (POIData.Meter_KW/60)
                        WHEN (POIData.Park_Potential_KW <= POIData.Meter_KW) OR POIData.Park_Potential_KW<0
                        THEN 0
                        END 
                ) AS [Curtailed_Energy_KWh],
                
                COUNT(CASE
                        WHEN InverterData.Valid = 1
                            AND InverterData.Active_Power > 0
                            AND  WeatherStationData.GPOA_1 > 100
                        THEN InverterData.fkInverterID
                        END
                ) AS [Inv_Count]
                


        FROM        [Comanche].[dbo].POIData INNER JOIN
                    [Comanche].[dbo].InverterData ON POIData.Timestamp_UTC = InverterData.Timestamp_UTC INNER JOIN
                    [Comanche].[dbo].WeatherStationData ON POIData.Timestamp_UTC = WeatherStationData.Timestamp_UTC

        WHERE       DATEADD(HOUR,-6,POIData.Timestamp_UTC) >= '2022-05-01' and DATEADD(HOUR,-6,POIData.Timestamp_UTC) < '2022-06-01'
        GROUP BY    POIData.Timestamp_UTC
    ),
    
    CTE_2 AS
    (
        SELECT  *,
                datepart(YY,DATEADD(HOUR,-6,[TimeDate])) as [Year],
                datepart(MM,DATEADD(HOUR,-6,[TimeDate])) as [Mon],
                datepart(DD,DATEADD(HOUR,-6,[TimeDate])) as [Day],
                AVG(CASE
                        WHEN [Inv_Count]<300
                        THEN [Inv_Count]/300
                        ELSE 1
                    END) AS 'Availability_InvTime(%)',

                (SUM([Sum_Meter_KWh]) + SUM([Curtailed_Energy_KWh]))/SUM([Sum_Expected_KWh]) as 'Energetic_Avail(%)'

        FROM CTE_1
        GROUP BY    
                    datepart(YY,DATEADD(HOUR,-6,[TimeDate])),
                    datepart(MM,DATEADD(HOUR,-6,[TimeDate])),
                    datepart(DD,DATEADD(HOUR,-6,[TimeDate]))
    )


SELECT * FROM CTE_2
                
ORDER BY    --POIData.Timestamp_UTC,
            [Year], [Mon], [Day]
```

'''

The code above results in following error:

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'CTE_1.TimeDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: In the definition of `CTE2` you attempt to reference the column `POIData.Timestamp_UTC`; there is no object defined with the name/alias `POIData` within `CTE2`. You also try to reference that same column in your final `SELECT` but only reference `CTE2`, and it is not aliased as `POIData`. That `GROUP BY` in the final query looks wrong too; you have a `SELECT *`, so that query is most certainly going to give a error about a column not appearing in the `GROUP BY` clause or not being aggregated.

Comment: Hi @Larnu - thank you for the feedback/suggestions. I've revised the code to assign an alias to 'POIData.Timestamp_UTC' in the first query and reference that alias in the CTE_2 query which seems to have gotten around the previous issue. I also moved the GROUP BY statements (for aggregating into daily values) into the CTE_2 query instead of the last query to hopefully avoid an error about any columns in the last query not being aggregated or included in the last GROUP BY statement. However, the error I'm getting now is related to 'CTE_1.TimeDate' not being aggregated or included in a GROUP BY

Comment: Also, apologies for the formatting issues...I'm still new to StackOverflow

Comment: The error is telling you the problem there. Why do you think `SELECT *` is going to work with an aggregate query?

Comment: `group by cast(dateadd(hour, -6, TimeDate)) as Date)` seems better to me.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?:

```
AVG(CASE WHEN Inv_Count < 300 THEN Inv_Count / 300 ELSE 1 END)
    OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, -6, TimeDate]) AS DATE))
    AS "Availability_InvTime(%)",

(
    SUM([Sum_Meter_KWh])         OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, -6, TimeDate]) AS DATE))
    +
    SUM([Curtailed_Energy_KWh])) OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, -6, TimeDate]) AS DATE))
)   /
    SUM([Sum_Expected_KWh])      OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, -6, TimeDate]) AS DATE))
    AS "Energetic_Avail(%)"
```

Be careful about integer division. You have at least one of those going on.